# Cannot use getMockBuilder in data providers in phpUnit v10+?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

In phpUnit 9 and below, we have been creating mocks in our data providers for testing. In v10+, data providers must now be `public static functions`, which means `$this->getMockBuilder()` cannot be used anymore.

For example, if we have a function `$foo->updateClient(Client $client)`, we would pass a mock of the client to the simulate different scenarios. In some cases, the mock will have a method that throws an exception for testing exceptions).

How do we add these mocks into the data provider if we cannot use `$this->getMockBuilder()` inside the providers anymore?

What's the best practice?

Comment: Please check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76853088/how-to-create-test-doubles-in-a-static-provider-in-phpunit